# Unable to add different block tag to my template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am trying to add different block tags inside a for loop but it raise an error

> Did you forget to register or load this tag?

But I register it

```
{% for todo in todo_list %}
{% if todo.complete %}{% else %}

        {{todo.text|capfirst|truncatechars:150}} </a> <br>
        <small class="text-muted">{{todo.content|capfirst}}{% empty %} {% endif %} </small> <hr>

{% endif %}   {% endfor %}
```

Thanks

Comment: *Which* tag is giving you this error?

Comment: It is when I add the tag {% empty %}.

Comment: But why are you doing that? `empty` relates to a `for` loop, not an `if` block? Why do you have it anyway, since it contains no content? Similarly why do you have an empty `if` before the else?

Comment: You are using two `endif` tags and also the `empty` tag is inside the `endif` tag

Comment: @DanielRoseman I was about to add a link for adding a new content if todo.content was empty using the empty tag block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into your problem, I think you need to try this:

```
{% for todo in todo_list %}
    {% if todo.complete %}
    {% else %}
        {{todo.text|capfirst|truncatechars:150}} </a> <br>
        {% if todo.content %}
            <small class="text-muted">{{todo.content|capfirst}} </small> <hr>
        {% else %}
            //do something 
        {% endif %}  
    {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```